# Unable to enable remote admin on MySQL 5.7 server on Ubuntu Server 16.04 using MySQL Workbench after system reinstall

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I had to reinstall my Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS.  The original install allowed remote admin on MySQL server (5.7) using a remote connection from MySQL Workbench.  I believe that the server has been configured as previously set up.

I have changed the bind-address in  the mysqld.cnf in the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ directory to the local address, to 0.0.0.0, to *, to the remote address, and commented the line out completely.  Nothing works.  Any attempt to connect using the Workbench results in a "'' is not allowed to connect" message.

I can use a telnet session and run MySQL through that but cannot get the Workbench application to connect no matter what I do.  Any suggestions of what to check or what I can do?

Comment: mysql --version returns:  mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (i686) using  EditLine wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem.  When I setup the user entry on the MySQL host, I apparently fat-fingered the IP address in the @hostname entry when granting privs.  When I added a second user using the hostname, it worked.  The final configuration in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf was for the bind-address entry to be set to the IP of the host machine.

Let the snarky comments begin.  :o)